# create matrix based on apply function in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, lapply

I have a matrix in R like this

```
dat <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), ncol = 4)
```

and i want to calculate the local variant (*lv*) of mutual information. For a pair of columns I can use the following code to find the *lv*

```
dat <- dat[,c(1,2)]
#install.packages("rinform")
library(rinform)
library(devtools)
#install_github("ELIFE-ASU/rinform")
#install_github("ELIFE-ASU/rinform", ref = "dev")
library(rinform)
mutual_info(dat)
mi <- mutual_info(dat, local = T)
mi <- as.matrix(mi)
```

which results in:

```
> mi
            [,1]
 [1,] -1.0000000
 [2,] -1.0000000
 [3,]  0.2223924
 [4,]  0.2223924
 [5,]  0.2223924
 [6,]  0.2223924
 [7,]  0.2223924
 [8,]  0.2223924
 [9,]  0.2223924
[10,]  0.2223924
[11,]  0.2223924
[12,]  0.2223924
[13,]  0.2223924
[14,]  0.2223924
[15,]  0.2223924
[16,]  0.2223924
[17,]  1.5849625
[18,]  1.5849625
[19,]  1.5849625
[20,] -1.5849625
```

How can I create a matrix that each column will have the `mi` values of each pair? Tried to use an apply function but couldn't make it work. The output result must be a `20x6` matrix with all pair-wise column combinations, i.e., the above mi procedure for `dat[,c(1,2)]`, `dat[,c(1,3)]`, `dat[,c(1,4)]`, `dat[,c(2,3)]`, `dat[,c(2,4)]`, `dat[,c(3,4)]`. Can someone help me?

Comment: How does your expected output (based on your given input) look like?

Comment: just edit it. Basically, the output must be a 20x6 matrix, meaning all possible column combinations .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't verify this approach since I don't know the `rinform` package. You could try

```r
apply(combn(1:4, 2), 2, function(i) mutual_info(dat[, i], locale = TRUE))
```

- `combn(1:4, 2)` creates a matrix of all possible of two elements from `1:4`.
- We use this as an input for the `apply` function to generate the result.

### Naming

If you save the new data into a matrix

```
new_data <- apply(combn(1:4, 2), 2, function(i) mutual_info(dat[, i], locale = TRUE))
```

you could name the columns using the same approach:

```r
colnames(new_data) <- apply(combn(1:4, 2), 2, function(i) paste0("V", i, collapse = ""))
```

Comment: that seems to work perfectly, but is there any way the output to have columns that indicate the vector combination? For example now the output  has as col names V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6. Can i get instead V1V2, V1V3, V1V4, etc...? I mean  is there an automatic way, i know i can use colnames and change them